# C Some headers include each other

Tags: c, gcc, header, c11

I can't solve next problem:

```c
//foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

#include "BAR.h"
#include "foos/foo_bazz.h"


typedef struct
{
   ...
} FOO;

// HERE I HAVE CALL `foo_baz(foo, bar);`
void
foo_bar(FOO *foo, BAR *bar);

#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

```c
//bar.h
#ifndef BAR_H_
#define BAR_H_

typedef struct
{
   ...
} BAR;

#endif /* BAR_H_ */
```

```c
//foos/foo_bazz.h
#ifndef FOO_BAZZ_H_
#define FOO_BAZZ_H_

#include "FOO.h"
#include "BAR.h"

void
foo_baz(FOO *foo, BAR *bar);


#endif /* FOO_BAZZ_H_ */
```

so it makes error like this:

```sh
foos/foo_bazz.h: error: unknown type name ‘FOO’; did you mean ‘FOO_H_’?
   16 |     FOO *foo,
      |     ^~~~
      |     FOO_H_
```

I tried to remove `#include "FOO.h"` from *foos/foo_bazz.h* and add `typedef struct FOO;` or `typedef struct FOO FOO;` but it didn't make some changes...

Also i tried to make inverse - i declared function in *FOO.h*, but result is the same.

Help me please, thank you

Comment: Why do you want to include foo_bazz in foo.h? It will fail for sure. The include in the foo.h in foo_bazz will not declare the type as it is already protected by the definitions. It makes no sense. Simply include foo_bazz.h in your `.c` file where you will have function and data definition. IMO X-Y problem.

Comment: cause I would have foo_bazz.h, foo_bakk.h etc. and implementation is big and it would be nicer if them would in different files

Comment: This isn't even a technical problem. Your program design should be sound and based on common sense - if it is, then you will not end up with circular dependencies. Each relation between a .h/.c pair to another .h/.c pair should be either a "uses" relation or "is a" relation. It doesn't make sense to have a relation "foo uses bar and bar uses foo". Nor does it make sense to have a "Ford is a car and a car is a Ford" relation. So I'd recommend to just back away from the C code and consider how to design the program differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to include foo_bazz in foo.h?

It will fail for sure. The inclusion of the foo.h in foo_bazz.h will not declare the type as it is already protected by the guards.

It makes no sense. Simply include foo_bazz.h in your `.c` file where you will have function and data definition. IMO X-Y problem.

Comment: Now i have link error `undefined reference to 'foo_baz'`

Comment: like i included *foos/foo_bazz.h* in *foo.c* and remove include from header

Comment: @MrZlo : the linker error is not related to the code you have posted.  You have not linked the _definition_ of `foo_bazz`, the code you have posted does not include a definition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the declaration:

```
void foo_baz(FOO *foo, BAR *bar);
```

is encountered before `FOO` is defined.  You can solve that problem by reordering the code in foo.h thus:

```
#include "BAR.h"

typedef struct
{
   ...
} FOO;

#include "foos/foo_bazz.h"

void
foo_bar(FOO *foo, BAR *bar);
```

That said @0___________ 's solution makes more sense in most cases, including this, but it is worth understanding why/how the problem occurred rather than simply blindly fixing it.